# get dbset at run time and return result as list of the base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I try to get the dbset for derived class when i have the name as string and need to return the result of the dbset in list of the parent class
like the following:
I have class person and customer
I need to get dbset of the customers to access the proper table using the entity frame work and return the results (all customers as person or Iperson)

Comment: You should provide the code you have already written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution as follow

```
   Type t = Type.GetType(AssemplyName);
   var dbs = db.Set(t);
   var dbsList = dbs as IQueryable<ILookupDetail>;
```

we get the type of the class then i used the set method to get the dbset by type
after that cast it as IQueryable from the parent interface